# Unable to unmarshal dynamodb result into struct with field defined as type interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I have the below struct definitions:

```
type Job struct {
    ID         string            `json:"id" dynamodbav:"id"`
    Ref        string            `json:"ref_id" dynamodbav:"ref_id"`
    Created    string            `json:"created_at,omitempty" dynamodbav:"created_at"`
    Stages     map[string]Status `json:"stages,omitempty" dynamodbav:"stages"`
}

// Status interface
type Status interface {
    GetMessage() string
}

// Failure struct
type Failure struct {
    Message string `json:"error_message,omitempty" dynamodbav:"message"`
}

// GetMessage returns the error message
func (f *Failure) GetMessage() string {
    return f.Message
}

// Success struct
type Success struct {
    Message string `json:"success_message,omitempty" dynamodbav:"message"`
}

// GetMessage returns the success message
func (s *Success) GetMessage() string {
    return s.Message
}
```

Where *Failure* and *Success* structs satisfies the Status interface

I am trying to unmarshal response from dynamodb into the Job struct as:

```
func getJobByID(id, table string) (*Job, error) {
    var (
        db = dynamodb.New(sess)

        key = map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "id": {
                S: aws.String(id),
            },
        }

        ip = &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
            TableName: aws.String(table),
            Key:       key,
        }
    )

    res, err := db.GetItem(ip)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if res.Item == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Not found")
    }

    var j *Job
    if err := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(res.Item, &j); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return j, nil
}
```

The dynamodb object looks something like

```
{
  "created_at": {
    "S": "2020-07-21T06:40:53Z"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "ca237361-7deb-4a28-872d-a602b9b1df67"
  },
  "stages": {
    "M": {
      "stage1": {
        "M": {
          "message": {
            "S": "Completed"
          }
        }
      },
      "stage2": {
        "M": {
          "message": {
            "S": "Completed"
          }
        }
      },
      "stage3": {
        "M": {
          "message": {
            "S": "Completed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "ref_id": {
    "S": "test-reference"
  }
}
```

The error that I get is :
`panic: reflect.Set: value of type map[string]interface {} is not assignable to type main.Status`

I think that the issue is that, I am trying to un-marshal a type `string` into an `interface`, and it is unable to get the concrete type of the interface which is causing the panic.

My question is how can I resolve this issue in an idiomatic manner.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the implementation of `dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap`, The final `Unmarshal` will fail as you are trying to unmarshal to a custom interface `Status`. This wont work as the runtime has no way to know the underlying struct to unmarshal into.

[Here's](https://play.golang.org/p/KoRcTYqqwun) a Playground example of a similar setup with just `json`.

Even on visual inspection of your json, you cannot be sure if
`"message": {"S": "Completed"}`  is a success or error.

You should replace `Status` in `map[string]Status` with a struct (like below) or even a `map[string]string` for the unmarshal to work

```
{
    Message string
}
```

Based on the failing example I shared earlier, [here](https://play.golang.org/p/KWb5DdE0tu8) is one of the ways you can make it work.

Comment: thanks for the response .. i was able to get the Unmarshal to work by replacing the Status to `map[string]string` but the issue is that this is a definition which has been used throughout the code base and there are logic is place based on the interface switch. Thus was looking if there exists an idiomatic way to get this to work. I realise now that a work around way needs to be implemented for this to work. Thanks ..

Comment: If rest of your code uses the same definition, then you can do something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/-CcZDjCWsVG) modification of the sample i shared in the answer.

Comment: that is exactly how i handled it actually .. Thank you for the reply .. I feel validated that my work around is not a weird way of getting it to work. :)